# Favicon Not loading in Django development as well as production

Tags: django, favicon

I have already tried all the solutions available as u can see in the code but No help. I can browse the favicon in my browser but not on webpage

[favicon](https://www.iitiansedu.com/static/images/favicon.ico)

U can see the no. of attempts

base.html

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="iitiansedu/static/image/favicon.png">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'iitiansedu/static/images/favicon.ico' %}"/>
        <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'iitiansedu/images/favicon.png' %}" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'iitiansedu/images/favicon.ico' %}">
        <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'images/favicon.png' %}">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="{% static 'images/apple-touch-icon.png' %}">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="{% static 'images/favicon-32x32.png' %}">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{% static 'images/favicon-16x16.png' %}">
        <link rel="manifest" href="{% static 'images/site.webmanifest' %}">
        <link rel="mask-icon" href="{% static 'images/safari-pinned-tab.svg' %}" color="#5bbad5">
```

url.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include
    from . import views
    from django.conf import settings
    from .views import SearchView
    
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
    from django.urls import include, path
    from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
    from .views import *
    from django.templatetags.static import static
    from django.conf import settings
    
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.urls import path
    from django.contrib import admin
    
    from carousel import views as carousel_views
    
    favicon_view = RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/favicon.ico', permanent=True)
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', views.HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
        # path('favicon.ico', RedirectView.as_view(url='static/favicon.ico')),
        path('favicon.ico', RedirectView.as_view(url=static('favicon.ico'))),
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled

```
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
            root /home/jagtar/iitiansedu;
        }
    
    location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
```

settings.py

```
if DEBUG:
            STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')]
    else:
            STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
    
    STATIC_URL = 'static/'
    
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

Comment: Use [`{% static ... %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#static).

Comment: Already using the same <!doctype html>
{% load static %}

{# Load the tag library #}
{% load bootstrap5 %}
{% load django_bootstrap5 %}

{# Load CSS and JavaScript #}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}

{# Display django.contrib.messages as Bootstrap alerts #}
{% bootstrap_messages %}

{% if 'use_i18n'|bootstrap_setting %}
    {% load i18n %}
    {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% endif %}

Comment: How is this a Bootstrap question?